# Does gcc's __builtin_constant_p always return 1 while evaluating a core constant expression?

Tags: c++, gcc, c++14

Here's the basic example I've been playing around with:

```
#include <limits>

constexpr inline int satadd_ce(int x, int y) {
    if (x >= 0 && y >= std::numeric_limits<int>::max() - x)
        return std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
    else if (x < 0 && y <= std::numeric_limits<int>::min() - x)
        return std::numeric_limits<int>::min();
    else
        return x + y;
}

[[gnu::const]] inline int satadd_asm(int x, int y) {
    int result;
    __asm__("addl %2, %0\n\t"
            "jno 2f\n\t"
            "jl 1f\n\t"
            "movl $0x7fffffff, %0\n\t"
            "jmp 2f\n\t"
            "1: movl $0x80000000, %0\n\t"
            "2:"
            : "=r"(result) : "0"(x), "rmi"(y));
    return result;
}    

constexpr inline int satadd(int x, int y) {
    if (__builtin_constant_p(x) && __builtin_constant_p(y))
        return satadd_ce(x, y);
    else
        return satadd_asm(x, y);
}

extern constexpr int n1 = satadd(2000000000, 1000000000);
extern constexpr int n2 = satadd(2000000000, -1000000000);
extern constexpr int n3 = satadd(-2000000000, 1000000000);
extern constexpr int n4 = satadd(-2000000000, -1000000000);
extern constexpr int n5 = satadd(satadd(2000000000, 1000000000), -1000000000);
```

The [GCC documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html#index-g_t_005f_005fbuiltin_005fconstant_005fp-4249) led me to believe this might not work when compiling with -O0:

> However, if you use it in an inlined function and pass an argument of the function as the argument to the built-in, GCC never returns 1 when you call the inline function with a string constant or compound literal (see Compound Literals) *and does not return 1 when you pass a constant numeric value to the inline function unless you specify the -O option*. (emphasis mine)

But in practice, the above code compiles fine with `g++-6 -O0`.  So is the GCC documentation possibly out of date, or are there other possible problems where `satadd` wouldn't work in a core constant expression but calling `satadd_ce` explicitly would?

(By the way, I do seem to remember some SSE version has dedicated saturated arithmetic instructions - but that's not really the point here, I just wanted to experiment with whether inline asm and a compile-time alternative could be combined in a single function callable both from normal code and core constant expressions.)

(Also, note that asm statements are explicitly forbidden to appear directly in `constexpr` functions, so at least `satadd_asm` must be a separate function.  Though if C++17's `constexpr if` were implemented in gcc and accepted `__builtin_constant_p` then that could potentially work.)

Comment: See https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=54021.  Looks like they explicitly handle `__builtin_constant_p` when evaluating `constexpr`s.  Probably not documented.

Comment: No thoughts on __builtin_constant_p.  Have you tried gcc-help@gcc.gnu.org?  Also, how about `asm("addl %1, %0\n\t" "jno 1f\n\t" "movl $0x7fffffff, %0\n\t" "adcl $0, %0\n\t" "1:" : "=r"(result) : "0"(x), "rmi"(y) : "cc");` or better yet `if (__builtin_add_overflow(x, y, &result)) { if (result < 0) return 0x7fffffff; else return 0x80000000; } return result;`?

Comment: @DavidWohlferd As I indicated in the question, I'm not that interested in optimizing the asm - if I were, I'd probably just use the corresponding SSE intrinsic.